# Are override properties set before the constructor runs?

Tags: c#

```
public class UserNotFoundException : Exception
{
    public UserNotFoundException()
    {
    }

    public UserNotFoundException(string? message) : base(message)
    {
    }

    public UserNotFoundException(string? message, Exception? innerException) : base(message, innerException)
    {
    }

    public override string Message => "Email or password is incorrect";
}
```

I wanted to know if my constructor can override `Message` property, which is what I want.

Which of the two is ran first the constructors or the Message property override set?

I know that I can do the following:

```
public class UserNotFoundException : Exception
{
    public UserNotFoundException()
    {
    }

    public UserNotFoundException(string? message = "Email or password is incorrect") : base(message)
    {
    }

    public UserNotFoundException(string? message = "Email or password is incorrect", Exception? innerException) : base(message, innerException)
    {
    }

}
```

But this feels like repeating myself.

Comment: You can put breakpoints and see the execution order by yourself 

Comment: `Message` is get-only: there is _nothing_ to "set".

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You override the base `Message`, so no, your constructor will not change that property. Why you don't use a constant?

```
public class UserNotFoundException : Exception
{
    private const string DEFAULT_MESSAGE = "Email or password is incorrect";

    public UserNotFoundException() : base(DEFAULT_MESSAGE)
    {
    }

    public UserNotFoundException(string? message) 
        : base(message ?? DEFAULT_MESSAGE)
    {
    }

    public UserNotFoundException(string? message, Exception? innerException) 
        : base(message ?? DEFAULT_MESSAGE, innerException)
    {
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You are overriding the `Message` property getter to always return that string, overriding the base behavior. So in effect the "message" that is passed into the constructor is never used.

The overridden property getter is run *when you get the property*. You are only *setting* it in the constructors that take it as a parameter.

You can easily verify this by throwing a new `UserNotFoundException`, passing in a different message, catching it, printing the message, and seeing what comes out.

If you *want* to allow for a custom message, then you can just set the default message in the parameterless constructor instead:

```
public UserNotFoundException() : base("Email or password is incorrect")
{
}

public UserNotFoundException(string? message) : base(message)
{
}

public UserNotFoundException(string? message, Exception? innerException) : base(message, innerException)
{
}
```

Comment: Good, but it does not use the standard message in case like `new UserNotFoundException(null, e)` which I believe the asker wants.

Answer (score 0):

You can also "chain" other constructor overloads in this class:

```cs
public class UserNotFoundException : Exception
{
    public UserNotFoundException() : this(null, null)
    {
    }

    public UserNotFoundException(string? message) : this(message, null)
    {
    }

    // new overload - remove it if you do not want it
    public UserNotFoundException(Exception? innerException) : this(null, innerException)
    {
    }

    public UserNotFoundException(string? message, Exception? innerException) 
        : base(message ?? "Email or password is incorrect", innerException)
    {
    }
}
```

As other answers say, when you pass a `message` up to the `base` constructor, you should not `override` the property `Message` in the way you do, without caring about the value of `base.Message`. Like the other answers I see now, I suggest you do not override that property.